# Why didn't Starfleet hunt down Klingon survivors in the aftermath of the Battle at Binary Stars?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In S01E04 of *Star Trek: Discovery* TV series, we learned that

> Flagship of Klingons was still there at the site of *Battle at Binary Stars* for whopping 6 months. That battle was a full-scale battle in which Admiral had died.

In the aftermath of the battle, why didn't Starfleet send more ships there to kill or capture Klingon survivors?

Comment: wasn't the Klingon ship still cloaked? I can't find a transcript that lists the Klingon dialogue, but when [Kor not Kor] visits, I seem to recall the conversation was regarding cloaking

Comment: @NKCampbell Nope. It was clearly visible as far as I remember. Yeah, Kor said that the ship was unique because it had cloaking technology.

Comment: Because Michael was busy being inducted into Discovery and since this whole series seems to be about her alone solving everything with little need to emphasize the critical roles of anyone else, she wasn't able to single handedly go back and kill the remaining Klingons. But don't worry. She and she alone will probably do so in an upcoming episode

Comment: Weren't they without warp power, basically? I thought that was clear in the episode. They were starving and trapped and almost abandoned by the Great Houses.

Comment: @KaiQing - Voq is also an important character so far. But we're only four episodes in. I'd not be surprised if we get a "Tilly episode," a "Stamets episode," etc. It took some time for the other STs to get in that zone.

Comment: @Adamant - It would be hard for them not to, but so far it really looks like they placing entirely too much emphasis on captain Sasha by demonstrating that she is the genuis level they wanted to portray with Kirk, but lived in an era where writers couldn't reflect it. I'm still watching, and I do like every other ST series, so it will probably grow on me. But right now all I see is the walking dead in star trek and the behavior of her characters being so similar really bothers me

Comment: Anyway, not sure I'd agree. First episode, first scene. Georgiou comes up with a plan to get spotted by *Shenzhou*, and Burnham doesn't figure it out. Not to mention Burnham's little mutiny and getting Captain Georgiou killed on a poorly planned capture mission, making a martyr for the Klingon Empire (out of grief at Georgiou's death?)...that was a bad chain of decisions.

Comment: And Burnham *is* a genius, yeah, and they are doing a decent job of portraying that. But she's a sight less of a Mary Sue than beloved old Kirk - as you yourself allude to. And much as I dislike ten-second solutions to complicated scientific issues, they're as *Star Trek* as apple pie. Nanoprobe bombs against species 8472, infinite speed with easily cured side effects, immediate synthesis of telekinesis molecules....

Comment: I always treat the first episodes like a baker's dozen. Toss it. nobody knows their roles yet, everyone's new. It's just to rope you in. In an alternate world we would know if her plan to attack the Klingons would have worked. The poor planning of that whole instance was (inferred) a reality because nobody listened to the genius solution in the first place. Had they done so, for all we know it would have gone another way entirely. But none the less, I'll stop ranting now. It's a very well done series and looks great. My little hang ups don't really mean anything.

Comment: @Adamant `Weren't they without warp power, basically? I thought that was clear in the episode. They were starving and trapped and almost abandoned by the Great Houses.` ~> So what? Situation was obviously in the favor of Starfleet. What do you want to say?

Comment: @ChristieRomanowski - Well, would there have been any reason for Starfleet to assume that there were Klingon survivors? They’d probably picked up all Starfleet survivors by that time, and they were close to (or in?) Klingon space…so would they really want to go poking around?

Comment: @Adamant Klingons were extinct till now. Suddenly, they are out of shadows. How powerful could they be?

Comment: @Christie - Why not ask Captain Georgiou?

Answer (score 4):

Starfleet had conclusively lost the battle, and the survivors, with T'Kuvma's ship disabled, got the the hell out of Dodge. With war being declared, Starfleet had better things to do then check up on an uninhabited frontier system they'd been driven out of and they'd have no reason to think the Klingons hadn't returned and to collect the ship. The survivors on the ship clearly had some communication capability: when Kol showed up, there was no surprise that T'Kuvma was dead, so word had clearly gone out. They were obviously just being ignored until Kol decided it was to his advantage to reappear: for all anyone knows, he'd been monitoring the situation so he could swoop in *just* at the right time, before they managed to get themselves moving and were desperate for supplies.

So, taking all this into account, the obvious answer is that Starfleet simply didn't consider the possibility the Klingons would just leave the ship stranded there, and with the pressure of the war they were too busy to bother checking an old battlefield out on the edge of Federation space that had no strategic value.

Comment: Also, since when does Starfleet hunt down survivors?